# prettyurl i cannot print the value

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to work with pretty url's. but it will go to 404.php
I don't know what is wrong with my .htaccess . I'm new with this prettyurl

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ test.php?id=$1

# not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .? /404.php [L]
```

in my test.php

here is the only code inside in my test.php

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $id;
}
```

but it's not printing.

I point my browser like this

`http://localhost/myprojectfolder/test/1`

structure of my project

```
myporjectfolder
   - index.php
   - .htaccess
   - test.php
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask... If that rewriting works as intended, then internally your script `test.php` _is_ called with the `$_GET['id']` parameter. You can use it the normal way...

Comment: but why is not printing 1 ?

Comment: Then obviously the rewriting is _not_ working as intended... Where is that `.htaccess` style file located in your folder hierarchy? Also make sure that you do not experience a caching issue, make a deep reload in your browser or disable the cache completely for testing...

Comment: the .htaccess is located inside myrpojectfolder together with index.php and test.php

Comment: it will execute the 404.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a couple of issues. You are pointing to `http://localhost/myprojectfolder/test/1` but you don't have `/test` in your rule. You have it only accepting digits only. Also you are not using a slash at the end of the URL but your rule says it should be there so that won't match either, unless you make it optional.

Also you are directing non existent files to 404.php. Well making pretty URL's which you are trying to do are non existent files as well. So that could cause problems.

Anyway, Try your rules this way for a URL like this

http://localhost/myprojectfolder/test/1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Or remove the /test folder which seems unnecessary anyway

http://localhost/myprojectfolder/1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: "Or remove the /test folder which seems unnecessary anyway" ,test is not a folder it's a php file

Comment: correct but you are using it in your URL, so your rule will not match unless you add it to the rewrite rule. See my first example. You **don't** need test in the URL, hence my second example.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now both of your example, I understand  now but what is [L] is it necessary ?

Comment: No problem. Yes, I recommend always using `L` so that when the rules match it will stop processing rules after it. Just makes it so when or if more rules are adding there is less chance of conflicts. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: can I ask, what if I have also php file like this account.php,members.php ,admin.php with no querystring,how can I execute them to browser ? I tried like this http://localhost/myprojectfolder/account but I get 404 not found.

Comment: I mean to remove .php extension

Comment: That should be a new question. Please do another.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078574/how-to-load-php-file-without-php-extension thank you in advance :)