# How to load php file without php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this working htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

my question for this if I have that rule on my htaccess how can I load php file that have no .php extension.

I add this to my htacess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It works fine `http://localhost/myprojectfolder/account`
but this will not work anymore `http://localhost/myprojectfolder/1`
how can I make them both working ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: black milk? try to understand what you edit and what it means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this URL `http://localhost/myprojectfolder/1` as in your other question. Then `test` shouldn't even be in the first rule. Then you can just make sure the file exists.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding another condition to your php extension rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

that ensures that when you add the `.php` extension, it actually points to a file that exists.

Comment: Or much better, just say:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]